# Dynamically decide which Fetch response method to use

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I work with a Backend API which returns different data types for different requests to the same endpoint. While a more appropriate solution would be to unify the data type returned, legacy, time and lack of tests play against this solution.

I am centralizing my `call` method to be used by other parts of the application which need to call the endpoint. This `call` method implements fetch. For information:

```
export default function call<P> (method: TCallMethod, payload: P, parameter?: string): Promise<IServerResponseObject> {
  const url: string = buildUrl(parameter);
  const body: string | null = payload ? JSON.stringify(payload) : null;

  return fetch(url, {
    method,
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${getAuthToken()}`
    },
    body
  }).then(async (response) => {
    let body: IServerResponseObjectBody = {
      message: '',
      code: ''
    };

    if (response) {
      body = await response.json();
    }

    return {
      status: response.status,
      body
    };
  });
}
```

As I receive data, I am using the `Response.json` method to decode it.

```
if (response) {
  body = await response.json();
}
```

The problem is that sometimes I receive no data (when the user is not authenticated - although that's an edge case) or the server responds with just a boolean.

In that case, the `json()` execution fails, because we are not handling JSON data.

ie:

```
FetchError: invalid json response body at http://localhost:4545/api/definition/isNameUnique/used%20name reason: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

I am wondering if there is a cleaner way than nesting `try/catches` to  determine which decode method to use from the ones available: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body#Methods

This feels like a potential solution: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body#Properties but the documentation is not too explicit and lacks examples on how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like you want to use `text` to read the response, then look at the resulting text and decide what to do. *Roughly*:

```
const text = await response.text();
if (!text) {
    // no response, act accordingly
} else if (reBool.test(text)) {
    // boolean response, determine whether it's true or false and act on it
} else {
    // JSON response, parse it
    data = JSON.parse(text);
    // ...then use it
}
```

...where `reBool` is a regular expression to test for the boolean the server sometimes returns, for instance `/^(?:true|false)$/i`.

If the response may have whitespace, you might `trim` the result of `response.text()`.

---

There are some unrelated things you might also want to do:

1. You're not checking for a successful response (this is a mistake a **lot** of people make, so many I wrote it up on my otherwise-anemic little blog). Check `response.ok` before using `json` or `text`, etc.
2. It doesn't make much sense to pass an `async` function into `then` as a callback. If you're going to go `async`, do it earlier, by making `call` an `async` function, then work with `await` throughout the body rather than mixing your metaphors...

Addressing those and folding in the main answer above (you'll need to adjust as necessary, either `IServerResponseObject` needs changing or you need to do something different with boolean responses):

```
const reBool = /^(?:true|false)$/i;

export default async function call<P> (method: TCallMethod, payload: P, parameter?: string): Promise<IServerResponseObject> {
  const url: string = buildUrl(parameter);
  const body: string | null = payload ? JSON.stringify(payload) : null;

  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method,
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${getAuthToken()}`
    },
    body
  });
  const {status} = response;
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error("HTTP error " + status); // Or `return {status};` or similar, but making it an error is useful
  }
  const text = (await response.text()).trim();
  let result = {status};
  if (!text) {
    // blank, act accordingly, perhaps:
    result.body = null;
  } else if (reBool.test(text)) {
    result.body = text === "true";
  } else {
    result.body = JSON.parse(text);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's indeed what I ended up trying after posting the question. It works although I don't really like the conditional behaviour. Also, thanks for the other recommendations, I'll look into it.

Comment: @Moustachiste - Yeah, as you noted in the question, you're sort of forced into the conditional behavior by the API. :-) I mean, if the bool is lierally `true` or `false` (lower case), that's also valid JSON, but then you'd just have to test the result of parsing to see if it was a boolean, which probably doesn't help things much...